# django encode UnicodeEncodeError at /

Tags: python, django

I have a problem in django project.

UnicodeEncodeError at /contact/1/view 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)

in Traceback:
views.py in single_contact

```
'vcard_str': unicode(VCard(contact)),
```

and all view

```
def single_contact(request, pk):
contact = Contact.objects.get(pk = pk)
if contact.group.user != request.user.profile:
    raise Http404
if request.method=="GET":
    emails = Email.objects.filter(contact = contact)
    hash = ''
    if emails:
        email = emails[0]
        hash = get_hash(email.email)
    addresses = Address.objects.filter(contact = contact)
    if addresses:
        address = addresses[0]
    phones = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(contact=contact)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/addressbook/single_contact.html',
            RequestContext(request, {
                'contact':contact, 'emails':emails, 'hash':hash,
                'addresses':addresses, 'phones':phones,
                'vcard_str': unicode(VCard(contact)),
            }))
elif request.method=="POST":
    contact.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('addressbook_index'))
else:
    raise Http404
```

what im doing wrong? how can i fix this ?

Comment: can you please also provide raw value for the `contact` value in VCard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try encoding in utf-8:

```
'vcard_str':  (VCard(contact)).encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

In models.py update VCard's **str** method to handle this exception.

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: if i upd this model, i got an error
UnicodeDecodeError at /contact/2/view

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 170: ordinal not in range(128)